# Define height of imported images in tikzpicture according to height of text node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex, diagrams

I'm using XeLaTeX to draw a sticker header with TikZ, using two images and some text. I want to define the height of those images *based on the height of the text node*, which is defined according to the lines of text. For instance, if the height of the text node is 2cm, the height of both images should be 2cm.

I tried to use `let` to extract the y-coordinate based on this calculation:

```
\path let \p1 = ($(text.north west) - (text.south west)$) in node ...
```

But it didn't work (I'm not sure if that's a valid approach, or if I used the syntax incorrectly).

So, what should I do to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Here's a MWE of what I'm trying to do (it doesn't have the above instruction):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=1.5cm}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north, font=\bfseries, align=flush center] (text) at ($(current page.north) + (0,-0.25)$) {This is the first line\\This is the second one};
    \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0pt] (image) at ($(text.west) + (-1.25,0)$) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}};
    \node[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (image) at ($(text.east) + (1.25,0)$) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output of the given file is this:

[image: Output of the attached code]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[font=\bfseries, align=flush center, anchor=north] (text) at ($(current page.north) + (0,-0.25)$) 
    {This is the first line\\This is the second one};
\path   let \p1 = ($(text.north)-(text.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node[anchor=east, inner sep=0pt] (image) at ($(text.west) + (-1.25,0)$)
            {\includegraphics[height=\n1]{example-image}}
        node[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (image) at ($(text.east) + (1.25,0)$) 
            {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Image will appear after second run.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! By the way, what are `veclen` and `\n`? I didn't found them in the manual (I'm sure they should be there).

Comment: Forget it. I finally found out: `veclen` is `sqrt(x^2+y^2)` and `\n` is a number register used in `let` =)

Comment: veclen: **vec**tor **len**gth. it is described in manual in many places: *4 Tutorial: Euclid*, than *14.15 The Let Operation* etc

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that (well, it's kinda difficult to get through that big manual) `>_<`